# (null) is not a valid win32 Application

Tags: installshield-le

I have created a winform application in visual studio 2012 on windows 7. I then created InstallShield project to create setup of this winform application. I run this setup on windows7/xp other than the development machine but i got the following error:-

(null) is not valid Win 32 application.

What iam doing wrong? Setup is working/running fine on development machine but not on other machines when running on windows 7/XP. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please check the registry and tell me what is the value for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<ServiceName>\ImagePath\ key